# How to access nested child values in Firebase

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure. [image: Click here for image of data structure.]

I am trying to get  database/content/xxxxxxx/matches for all the 'xxxxxxx' items under content into an `Array list` so that I can iterate the `Array list` and grab all the images for the items that match. For example, for Avery-Fit Solid Pant, I want to get the image for Blouse with Flared Sleeve, High-Neck Stripe Top, etc. and then move to Bell Sleeve Dress and do the same. Below is what I have tried, but it is not working.

```
 matchRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/content");

        matchRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    SliderItems mvalue = dataSnapshot.getValue(SliderItems.class);
                    DataSnapshot contentSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("/matches");
                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> matchSnapShot = contentSnapshot.getChildren();
                       for (DataSnapshot match : matchSnapShot){
                           SliderItems c = match.getValue(SliderItems.class);
                        matchImages.add(c);

                    }

                startMatchRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

I was pretty sure that my database was not structured properly and restructured it as follows. [image: See alternate structure here.] I think this is a more appropriate structure. I can access matches to populate an `Array list`. How do I iterate the `Array list` for each entry to find the members that are 'true' and then get the images from content for each 'true' member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you listen for the value of `/content` you get a snapshot that has all content in it. To get to the individual content items (which have a `matches` property), you need to loop over the children of the snapshot:

```
matchRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/content");

matchRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            SliderItems mvalue = itemSnapshot.getValue(SliderItems.class);
            DataSnapshot contentSnapshot = itemSnapshot.child("/matches");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> matchSnapShot = contentSnapshot.getChildren();
               for (DataSnapshot match : matchSnapShot){
                   SliderItems c = match.getValue(SliderItems.class);
                matchImages.add(c);

            }
        }
        startMatchRecyclerView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could use a `ChildEventListener`, in which case you can get rid of the `for` loop I added, since its `onChildAdded` will then already fire on what I called `itemSnapshot` in my code.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen This worked beautifully!